# Openpyxl How to get value from worksheet by index

Tags: excel, openpyxl

This has been asked a few times, but none of the old answers are working for me.

I traverse the first row in a sheet, but my method hits a 'None' value before it gets to the first empty cell. So it looks like the column order is not the same as that shown in Excel, and that empty columns are mixed in. This is in openpyxl version: 2.6.2

```
def countActiveColumns(sheet):
    count = 0
    # note max_row = 1 here
    for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, min_col=1, max_row=1, max_col=1000):
        for cell in row:
            print('countActiveColumns - content %s' %(cell.value))
            if cell.value == None:
                print('countActiveColumns - count %s' %(count))
                return count
            count += 1
```

So my first row contains "Currency Id", "Plural Name", "Singular Name", "startBalance", "Image Path", "Catalog Image" but the output is

```
New SheetInfo (Currencies) -> table currencies
countActiveColumns - content Currency Id
countActiveColumns - content Plural Name
countActiveColumns - content Singular Name
countActiveColumns - content Image Path
countActiveColumns - content None
countActiveColumns - count 4
```

I have also tried this with similar results

```
def old_countActiveColumns(sheet):
    count = 0
    for col in range(1, 100):
        value = sheet.cell(1, col).value
        print('countActiveColumns - value %s' %(value))
        if value != None:
            print('countActiveColumns - %d columns' %(col-1))
            return col-1
```

Comment: Please explain what the actual problem is. At the moment it looks like there is an empty cell after "Image Path".

Comment: I'm expecting it to find 6 non-empty cells in a row before hitting the first empty cell. It's only finding 4, and the columns are not in the same order as they are in the sheet.

Comment: Maybe there is a hidden or merged cell. openpyxl **does** iterate over the cells in order.